Combining UR10e with two canopen driven joints
As the title says, I'm trying to augment the UR10e with additional joints, which are driven with canopen_motor_node.
I'm able to drive both the UR10e and the canopen joints separately, but struggling to combine them.

I set up the kinematic chain in the URDF file, which contains the canopen driven joints and the UR10e. I used a loose joint, which simply connects the end of the canopen driven part with the base_link of UR10e.

I pass the aforementioned file as robot_description param, and I'm able to start the UR10e with this augmented robot_description (i.e., the robot starts as it needs to be, its transforms are visualized according to the current state, just in RViZ I see some missing transforms (connected to the additional joints) due to the fact that the canopen motor node is not started yet)

After step 2, I start the canopen_motor_node in a separate launch file, in which I have the following base controller:


  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints:
    - base0_joint_1
    - base0_joint_2

  required_drive_mode: 7

I get basically the error when the controller_manager tries to spawn this base_joint_controller. The error message is the following:
[ERROR] [1712926364.683354865]: Failed to initialize the controller
[ERROR] [1712926364.683440950]: Initializing controller 'base_joint_controller' failed
[ERROR] [1712926364.688503322]: Could not start controller with name 'base_joint_controller' because no controller with this name exists

I have the feeling that somewhere deep the hardware_interface (set up by the UR) needs to be modified, but have no experience in these very detailed manipulations.
Can someone help me solving this problem?
Thank you in advance,
Best regards.

how does your full ros2_control yaml look like? have you added the controller incl. its type to the controller_manager section? otherwise you have to give it as parameter to the spawner (see -t here)

Thanks for the feedback. It is ros1, and I use the default ur10e_controllers.yaml file augmented with the canopen-related joints, as I wrote in step 3 I have this for canopen joints: `base_joint_controller:
type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
joints:
- base0_joint_1
- base0_joint_2
required_drive_mode: 7` I think the problem is with the hardware interface, since one one hand UR10e sets it up first, then canopen-motor-node sets up another one, thereby creating a conflict.

Maybe I need to have two controller_manager instances? Since UR initializes one, then canopen-motor-node does includes a controller_manager instance as well, and that makes a conflict? I'm just guessing...

Sorry, I have not seen that you are working on ROS. Please add the ROS distro you are using to your initial question.

I have updated the ROS distro, but did not find any solution so far. I found this link which says that  2 controller_managers would solve the problem, but I have no idea how to set this up. Do you have any clue what should I do?

I tried to describe both the problem and complete setup here [link] (https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/110705/modular-robot-canopen-base-universal-robot-arm-controller-manager-setup-for-d) (I could not continue to edit this post since i did not login previously)
