Modular robot (canopen base+ universal robot arm) controller_manager setup for different hardware interfaces
I have a modular robot composed of a mobile base and an arm. The mobile base is driven with two CANopen-driven joints, while the arm is an UR10e universal robot. I’m able to drive BOTH the mobile base and UR10e separately, however I struggle to combine them, i.e., to be able to control both sub-robots in ROS (I don’t want to control them simultaneously, just to have them available under controller_manager).
I found this answer here, which states that I can have separate controller_manager nodes for each sub-robot (e.g. base_controller_manager and arm_controller_manager), which would be perfect for me, however I’m not able to solve this, thereby I’m here asking for help. I will try to describe what I have as follows.
Mobile base:

CANopen is based on socketcan driver and I set up the base in ROS with canopen_motor_node.

The URDF sets up the kinematic chain as follows:
world → base0_link0 → base0_link1→ base0_link2
I have two CANopen joints as follows:


base0_joint_1: connects base0_link0 with base0_link1
base0_joint_2: connects base0_link1 with base0_link2
The aforementioned joints have the following transmission_block:
type: transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission
hardwareInterface: hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface

I’m able to control these joints with a base_joint_controller that is spawned by the controller_manager
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints:
    - base0_joint_1
    - base0_joint_2

  required_drive_mode: 7```




Arm:

The UR10e robot is controlled based on the official materials supplied here.

Basically, the URDF is set up in ur10e.xacro file, which forms the kinematic chain from base_link to tool0 link. I found that each joint has the transmission_block:
type: transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission
hardwareInterface: hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface

I’m able to control the arm with the default scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller that is spawned by the controller_manager along with other controllers (joint_state_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller).


Mobile base + Arm (i.e., the problem):

I set up a new URDF file, which combines the two sub-robots, i.e., I have a kinematic chain:
world (base) → base0_link0 (base) → base0_link1 (base)→ base0_link2 (base) → base_link (UR10e)→ … → tool0 (UR10e)

Based on the kinematic chain I have now 8 joints, these are:
base0_joint_1,base0_joint_2,shoulder_pan_joint,shoulder_lift_joint,elbow_joint,wrist_1_joint,wrist_2_joint,wrist_3_joint
The type and hardwareInterface of each joint are: transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission and hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface (these are defined in the URDF file).
I have checked the URDF file in RViZ, with the help of robot_state_publisher and joint_state_publisher nodes; it is set up correctly.

I start the UR10e with the new URDF file (robot_description parameter in the launch file) without problems, the UR10e can be controlled with the scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller, the controller_manager shows the joint_state_controller,  scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller controllers running (GREEN).

Obviously: the TF tree is separated at this point, because only the UR10e-related controllers are running, therefore I see two trees: base_link → tool0 and world→ base0_link0
Note: the controllers are spawned with the <node name="ros_control_controller_spawner" node name

NEXT: I would like to start the the canopen-driven joints as I did before. I start the canopen_motor_node, WHICH basically kills the UR10e controllers which worked in the previous step (i.e., I cannot run – load and start - anymore the joint_state_controller,  scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller controllers (GRAY color))

Instead, the base_joint_controller (used by the canopen joints) can be used to drive the base, but the UR10e controllers are killed.
Note: the controllers are spawned with the <node name="controller_spawner_can" node name
So, I use separate controller manager nodes to spawn the UR10e controllers and canopen-driven controllers.
What to do? Some thoughts:

I think that UR10e sets up its hardware_interface, which is then overwritten by canopen_motor_node. Is this the problem? It is written here that The node includes a controller_manager instance. Maybe that is the problem?
I found the combined_robot_hw here, but that one would require two hardware interfaces, which I don’t really have. I have the UR10e hardware_interface, and the other one is set up by the canopen_motor_node under the hood. It seems difficult.
I found promising here to have, two controller_managers, but I’m unable to set this up correctly.

Can anyone help me in this problem?
Thanks in advance.

be aware that the link is for ros2_control which is very different to ros_control as you are using.
